# implementing private functions for a window.object

Tags: javascript, global

I'm creating a wrapper for an API that will be used in a couple different applications.

I'm using a global object and placing the various functions into that object as different keys. So I'll have:

```
window.globalContainer = {
  APIEndpoint1: function(){
    make API call and resolve result
  },
  APIEndpoint2: function(){},
  ...
}
```

All the meat of the API calls are directly in the functions. That is, you could go to window.globalContainer.APIEndpoint1 from the console and see the entire function.

Is this generally bad practice for something that's used across multiple applications and acts as a helper library? Or is this acceptable? I looked at jQuery in the console and it seemed to do much of the same. If it is frowned upon, how do I implement private functions within the global object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good place to start is anonymous closures:

```
(function (global) {
    var foo = global.foo || {};
    //accessible
    foo.publicVar = 5;
    foo.publicFcn = function (a, b) {
        privateFcn(a, b);
        ...
    };
    //not accessible
    var privateVar = 5;
    function privateFcn(a, b) {
        ...
    }

    global.foo = foo;
})(window)
```

With these you can pretty intuitively build a library and *not* pollute the namespace.

You explicitly say which variables and functions you want to be made accessible.

Comment: @m-davis, I have multiple objects tied onto window.foo. I'm running into an error where the only way I can add, say, `foo.bar.get` is by first instantiating `foo.bar` with `foo.bar={}` Is there a better way to dynamically declare these new objects?

Comment: @Somethingismissing as far as I know, that is the best way. You could do it more compactly like so: `foo.bar = {get : function (params) {return baz;},  set : function (param) {return baz = param;} }`. You could also wait until just before the `global.foo` statement and say `foo.bar = bar`. That way you could build `bar` to be any function, object, or variable above that statement. (Note, you would have to instantiate `var bar = {};` or `function bar (...) {...}` anyways)

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can use an IIFE to implement private functions/properties.

```
 window.globalContainer = function () {
      //what ever you define here is not accessible outside. Only the API in 
      //the returned object is accessible outside

      function private1() {
           make API call and resolve result
      }

      return {
          APIEndpoint1: function(){
            private1();
          },
          APIEndpoint2: function(){},
          ...
      }
    }();
```